# How to display ajax results without ending a php script? Jquery - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the PHP Imap Library along with Ajax to display search results from within emails.  The main problem I am finding is that providers (Hotmail in particular) will cut off connection after 6 or 7 connections in close proximity of time.

Instead of imap_connect() in each script, I'd like to connect once and then continuously display information with ajax.  I just have no idea how to do this.  The problem is that I need to spit out data through the ajax.  Is there any way to return information without ending the PHP program through jquery?

I could also potentially do this if I pass the imap connection variable `$connection` to the php query instead of calling it, but unsure how to pass it.  Here's how I'm currently passing the variables.

```
    var dataString='email=<?php echo $email_address; ?>&connection=<?php echo $connection; ?>&password=<?php echo $password; ?>&server=<?php echo $server;?>&daysago='+daysago+'&num='+num;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
    url: "fastsearch.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg){
```

Link to Imap Connect (and general php imap library):
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Answer (score 2):

I've done "socket emulation" programming in PHP and jQuery in the past, which is a sort of COMET based approach to keep long connections.

This is really a shining example of where Node.js is favorable to web application development as for the easily installable and usable Socket.io library.

Node.js aside, you have a few options, forking a process that keeps your connections alive and persistent, not connecting live every time someone signs in (use an async task manager like celery), and using a COMET approach which is basically an infinite while loop that constantly spits out data to the client side.  The latter would keep a single connection open, but would also be highly unstable, non-performant, and by using PHP the wrong tool for the job.

I'd urge you to reconsider your PHP dependency for this specific task, and instead move in favor to a library that was designed for this specific server push/persistence.